# Delay executing the spring batch job

Tags: java-8, spring-batch

I am writing a custom scheduler for a distributed application by using spring batch and so far all the scenarios have been covered by the spring-batch framework. I have to create a fault tolerant scheduler that can recover from all the crashes. One scenario is:
I have a custom table where I store the job_execution_id from spring batch. I am using AsyncTaskExecutor so I get the JobExecution without waiting for the entire job to complete. I need to update this job_execution_id in my custom table so that I can track all the jobs and steps related to this job execution. How ever if application crashes before updating the job then there is some sort of manual intervention required. Is it possible to delay the execution of the job until I update the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to delay the execution of the job until I update the table?

Scheduling is not part of the framework. You need to implement the solution yourself.